# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm getting an error and I don't know how to resolve it..

The error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\records\delete-confirm.php on line 7

Line 7 is:

```
echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('.modal-" . $row->id . "').hide();$('#delete-" . $row->id . "').click(function(){$('.modal-" . $row->id . "').show();});$('#cancel-" . $row->id . "').click(function(){$('.modal-" . $row->id . "').hide();});});</script>";
```

I have checked the whole line but there seems no errors in there? What is going wrong here?

Comment: Variables are parsed in double quoted strings: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/3933332 (Also see, more general: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/3933332)

Comment: Replace double-quotes with single-quotes. (and single with double)

Answer (score 5):

By using double quotes `"` in an `echo` statement, PHP *reads* the value of the content inside the quotes. Single quotes `'` *assign* a value to what's between the quotes.

```
$variable = 'Mia';  // assigns the value Mia to the $variable
echo '$variable';   // output is $variable;
echo "$variable";   // output is Mia;
```

In your example, wrap literal output in single quotes instead of double quotes and it will solve your problem.

```
echo '<div class="example" id="' . $variable . '">';
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's (technically) [enough](https://3v4l.org/N4D9A) to change every `{$` to `{ $` (i.e. separated by a space) as in

```
echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $('.modal-" . $row->id . "').hide();$('#delete-" . $row->id . "').click(function(){ $('.modal-" . $row->id . "').show();});$('#cancel-" . $row->id . "').click(function(){ $('.modal-" . $row->id . "').hide();});});</script>";
```

(or change the double-quoted php string to a single-quoted one, as mentioned earlier)

PHP switches in a slightly different parsing mode when you use `"....{$var}..."` instead of `"... $var ..."` and in your case it ticks the parser off because `$(` makes no sense to it.

But do those few whitespaces, necessary to make the code human readable,  really hurt?

```
<?php
echo '<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".modal-' . $row->id . '").hide();
        $("#delete-' . $row->id . '").click(function(){
            $(".modal-' . $row->id . '").show();
        });
        $("#cancel-' . $row->id . '").click(function(){
            $(".modal-' . $row->id . '").hide();
        });
    });
</script>';
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem has been solved with help from your first example. About to make the code readable for humans, I have multiple `<tr></tr>` and inside those tags there's the jquery script. If I make the code human readable, these `<tr></tr>` tags will become a huge part of the source code. Thanks for helping and have a nice weekend!

Comment: Oh, you're putting that code "into" multiple (read: many, many) tags? Have you considered using e.g. a [data- attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) just for the element id and then just let the (single instance) code figure it out?

Comment: I have not considered that because I have yet to learn the data attribute part. I know how to use it in some ways, but for now I'll stick to the old school way. :]